# How to test LiveData in ViewModel using coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am trying to test a function that executes a block of code launching a new coroutine, using this extension function:

```
fun ViewModel.execute(block: () -> Unit) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { block() }
```

Basically is launching a new coroutine in a ViewModel scope.

In my ViewModel, I use this function to invoke a use case and the result of this invocation, is a Kotlin Result, so I call the function fold to get the result and make the implementation for the success and the failure cases.

```
   fun function() {
        execute {
            useCase.invoke()
            ).fold(
                onSuccess = { },
                onFailure = { }
            )
        }
    }
```

In any of these cases, I am updating a LiveData object stored in my ViewModel.

I have tried to use the InstantExecutionRule

```
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

and I have also tried to set the coroutine context using

```
@get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()
```

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class TestCoroutineRule : TestRule {

    val testCoroutineDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description) = object : Statement() {
        @Throws(Throwable::class)
        override fun evaluate() {
            Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)

            base.evaluate()

            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }

    fun runTest(block: suspend TestScope.() -> Unit) = testScope.runTest { block() }
}
```

But whenever I call this function from the test class, I get an error because the function inside the fold function (onSuccess and onFailure cases) is not called and the LiveData is not updated.

Do I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the class definition for the return type of the usecase.invoke(), and particularly the definition of the fold function?

Comment: Also if the fold function looks good I'd be interested to see on example of the use of livedata

Comment: Hi @ryankuck, the fold function is the one defined in the Kotlin.Result class (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/). The use of the LiveData inside that fold function is just updating the Livedata object stored in the ViewModel that is used to manage events (a sealed class)